# facebook comment - get comment count for URL?

Tags: c#, facebook, api, facebook-graph-api

My page uses facebook comment social plugin.

Is it possible to display only the comment count icon? seperately somewhere else? so we know how many users commented? either by getting the value by the social plugin or via API or other means?

Answer (score 0):

Try this service: http://sharedcount.com/ it also counts likes, shares etc..